# Range of a function of two variable

Tags: analysis

How to find $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ if $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$

$$f(x,y)=(e^{x+y}+e^{x-y},e^{x+y}-e^{x-y} )$$

Comment: Well, the range of $(u,v)=(e^{x+y},e^{x-y})$ as $x,y$ vary is just $\{x>0,y>0\}$, so you just need to find the range of $(u+v,u-v)$ for positive $u$ and $v$.